# How to get external transaction using python

Tags: transactions, web3.py, internal-transactions

I am trying to test their [code](https://github.com/blockchain-unica/ethereum-ponzi)  in order to detect the Ponzi smart contracts. When I run their code following error occurred to get the external transactions. Here is their code ;

```
for addr in ponzi:
    if (verbose): print("Retrieving transactions of contract ",addr,"... ",end=" ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print("Address: ", addr)
    api = Account(address=addr, api_key=key)
    print("api: ", api)
    text = api.get_ext_transactions()
    tint = api.get_int_transactions()
```

The value of addr = "0xf45717552f12ef7cb65e95476f217ea008167ae3"

The value api = "<etherscan.accounts.Account object at 0x00000075B4C67388>"

but when execution reaches at api.get_ext_transactions() it gives following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ponzi-stats.py", line 133,
> in 
> text = api.get_ext_transactions() AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'get_ext_transactions'

And I think this error will also be appeared in next to get internal transactions.

Now my question is how to get external/internal transactions using web2.py. What I have to import, install, etc...

**EDIT**: In their code they have used `from etherscan.accounts import Account`. That's why I have installed py-etherscan-api by using this command `python -m pip install py-etherscan-api` . I am not sure this is right or wrong ...